# Через что реализовать получение списка клиентов в сети

Tags: c#, .net

Клиентам приходит UDP пакет с данными, они по TCP подключаются к серверу и это подключение постоянно висит, что требует много ресурсов, так же при (некорректном) закрытии сервера, после некоторое время, не удается создать его на том же порту.

Как лучше сделать живой онлайн, желательно не посылая каждые пару секунду оповещения от клиентов?

**.net 3.5**

Comment: WCF + NetTcpBinding, доступны в 3.5, все что касается TCP реализовано достаточно эффективно и работает "из коробки" по событиям. Udp правда придется сбоку прикручивать, если он очень нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы можно было в любой момент пересоздать слушающий сокет, лучше использовать опцию ReuseAddress, с ней можно будет спокойно закрыть сервер, и тут же снова открыть без ожидания. А каждые пару секунд оповещения слать не обязательно.